# Why is angular not able to access prop in a binding even though the object is available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

On a select the following passes the old value of a scoped object in as a parameter to a function;

```
ng-change="updateArrangement({{activeTune.arrangement}})"
```

However when trying to pass in an individual property I get an undefined error, even though `key` is defined and `$scope.activeTune.arrangement` has `key` defined before this particular view is rendered.

```
ng-change="updateArrangement({{activeTune.arrangement.key}})"
```

Can anyone explain what it is about angular's treating of bindings that makes this behaviour happen?

Comment: Is `activeTune.arrangement` defined in the same scope as the element that contains the `ng-change` or a inherited parent scope?

Comment: ng-change is expecting an expression. Does it work if you remove the curly braces?

Comment: @Martin -using the curly braces is the correct way to pass in the value of a property (I've used it extensively elsewhere in my templates)

Comment: @Adam_Thomas it's defined on $rootScope, although I copy it to a property on the local $scope (first line of the controller) and have tried referencing this instead but it still doesn't work

Comment: You're not interested in passing the newly selected value to the `updateArrangement()` function, you want to pass a different model to it?

Comment: I created a [working CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yiDkB) that shows the solution as I understand the question.